# Python regular expression 'BA/BMF/ABCDEJF/

Tags: python-3.x, python-re, python-regex

Need help with Regex expression, which i'm trying to work on. Below is the example that i'm trying to work on

**Code**

```
import re


CommonPrefixes = [{'Prefix': 'BA/BMF/ABCDEJF/'}, {'Prefix': 'AG/CRBA_CORE/ABCDEJF/'}, {'Prefix': 'DC/KAT/pages-modified/'}]

res = [re.sub("(^\w+/)|(^\w+\/|/)|(/$)",'',x["Prefix"]) for x in CommonPrefixes]

print(res)
```

Output I'm getting is below

**OutPut**

```
['BMFABCDEJF', 'CRBA_COREABCDEJF', 'KATpages-modified']
```

Output I'm looking for

**Expected output**

```
['ABCDEJF', 'ABCDEJF', 'pages-modified']
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the last substring between 2 slashes for each of your strings.
Here's the Regex you want to use: `/([\w_-]+)/$`.
However, you'll want to use that regex with the function `re.search`, instead of using `re.sub` to remove the rest of the string, plus this will be more efficient.

```py
import re


CommonPrefixes = [{'Prefix': 'BA/BMF/ABCDEJF/'}, {'Prefix': 'AG/CRBA_CORE/ABCDEJF/'}, {'Prefix': 'DC/KAT/pages-modified/'}]

res = [re.search(r"/([\w_-]+)/$",x["Prefix"]).group(1) for x in CommonPrefixes]

print(res)
```

Please beware that this might error if some of your `CommonPrefixes` don't match, so you might want to add a bit of error handling if required.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `re.search()` and Named Groups?

```
res = [re.search(r”.+/.+/(?P<result>.+)/”, x[“Prefix”])[“result”] for x in CommonPrefixes]
```